# Who are the other immortals in the Vampire Chronicles?

Tags: vampire-chronicles

I remember Marius telling Lestat that there were other immortals which were not vampires (Possibly in *The Vampire Lestat*). That he had seen them on a few occasions over the course of a century or more. Were these other immortals ever identified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only one she has written about is Ramses the Damned.  In that book several others were made with the elixir of life, but as Ramses was sleeping throughout Marius' life, and the immortals made in Ramses the Damned were not alive yet it is assumed he has made other immortals throughout the years that have not been written about.  As Marius said, at least one is female.

Answer (score 3):

The other Immortals refers to the now extended universe of Anne Rice, they would be the vivid blue eyed Immortals made from the Elixir of Life from the Ramses The Damned series. The Morphenkinder/Werewolves that do not age and are invulnerable to disease from The Wolf Gift series. The Forest Gentry- spirits who were once human yet chose to remain on earth and are able to create solid bodies for themselves by drawing microscopic particles of solid matter to themselves, also from The Wolf Gift series. The Taltos that age rapidly from birth to full adulthood in mere days and who are atleast 7 ft tall, who also cease to age upon becoming fully grown, featured in the Mayfair Witches series. The Replimoids/aliens from the star system known as Bravenna who made Amel an Immortal body, featured in the book Prince Lestat and The Realms of Atlantis. In The Wolf Gift series I believe the Werewolves servants are subservient Elves/Fairies who do not age either and exist to serve other Immortals as servants in exchange for their protection as they are weak and peaceful beings. I don’t know if she’s mentioned any others but I do so wish she was still alive to continue her beautiful fictional universe. :(

Comment: Done, books added, and split into sentences.  :)

Comment: Much better, thank you! +1

Answer (score 2):

I never finished the more recent books, but I don't think they were ever directly identified; I believe it was Anne Rice's way of setting up a possible cross-over to some of her other books, like Servant of the Bones and Ramses the Damned.  (Much as she brought in the Mayfair Witches in some of the later Vampire books.)

Comment: This is the correct answer, or at least part of it.  Mummies were one of the other immortals who walked in the light that Marius feared.  It's possible that the ghost/demon in the witches series was another type of immortal.

Answer (score 2):

It has been rumored that Anne Rice did this intentionally in order to set the stage for other books like for the new Werewolf book that is about to come out. However, there is no evidence that this rumor is true.

The more likely explanation, is that when Marius said "other immortals", it was in the context which was regarding "other vampires".

QUOTE:

> "He spends his time as a vampire, observing, roaming and studying,
>   never evoking danger from **other immortals**. Having grown up around the
>   rich influences of sculptors, painters and poets, Vittorio still
>   spends most of his nights roaming the city streets of Florence. After
>   a little minor background history and a quote from Sheridan Le Fanu,
>   his story begins."

Also:

> "Right now I must explain that before this adventure commenced, I was
>   also grieving for the **other immortals** I had known and loved, because
>   they had long ago scattered from our last late-twentieth century
>   gathering place. Folly to think we wanted to create a coven again.
>   They had one by one disappeared into time and the world, which was
>   inevitable."

As you see, the context in these quotes is regarding other vampires.

It is this dynamic, multifaceted language that makes Anne Rice's writings so interesting, fascinating, and transfixing.

Comment: No, Marius says there are other Immortals that ARE NOT VAMPIRES, that he has seen them. He wasn't speaking of other vampires. I don't particularly want to go through tons of internet pages to find the exact quote. Mine are audiobooks.

Answer (score 0):

No. Based on recent books they were either mummies or ghosts/spirits who'd learned to form bodies for themselves by magnetically drawing particles out of the air to themselves.

Comment: Can you add a reference for this?

Comment: The Mummy, and Prince Lestat, where the identities of the other immortals is revealed.